# Can questions about IDEs be asked here - If not then where(don't suggest stackoverflow)?

Tags: discussion, support

I am confused whether questions about IDEs can be asked on [programmers main website](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or not? Questions such as which IDEs have this feature? An example would be [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439620/an-ide-with-drag-and-drop-feature-for-python-2-7-tkinter).

I asked such questions on stackoverflow before being told to ask on superuser or other websites. I [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113087/software-tools-in-faq-is-too-hazy), [asked this question on its meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181041/confusion-regarding-the-faq-and-a-question) but it seems the [questions about IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439620/an-ide-with-drag-and-drop-feature-for-python-2-7-tkinter) are still being put on hold.

So before posting questions on programmers I decided to ask it on its meta.

- Should I ask questions about IDEs here or not?
- If not then which websites do they belong to?
- Is there a question about the where I can ask questions not fitting on this website. Like [the one on Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow).

EDIT:

I have looked at the [about page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It says to ask such questions on stackoverflow. But on stackoverflow I have been told otherwise.

Comment: Tangental question on MSO [How can I ask question from specific users about the reason for closing a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187155/how-can-i-ask-question-from-specific-users-about-the-reason-for-closing-a-questi) (it isn't really about that, but rather the MSO question about the IDE question close).

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> software tools commonly used by programmers

Stackoverflow is the place to ask about IDEs.

EDIT: can you point where you have been told that this was off-topic on SO?

about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439620/an-ide-with-drag-and-drop-feature-for-python-2-7-tkinter) question:

It wasn't closed because it was about IDEs. It was closed because you asked for a software recommendation. These are off-topic because they are very difficult to answer in a good way.

EDIT (2):

I don't think you will find a good place on stackexchange for this type of question. Having a clear focus is a big advantage to keep the place professionnal, and attract skilled people on specific topics. That means (sadly) that some questions cannot be asked.

Some question like yours were not closed, and are sometimes highly upvoted. this is part due to historical reasons, and part to the fact that people enforcing the rules are not perfect :-)

Comment: This question specifically mentions `Questions such as which IDEs have this feature?`. I am not looking for a recommendation. I just couldn't find any such IDE via google or any other resources that I have looked through for Tkinter . e.g. [This link on quora](http://www.quora.com/Python-programming-language-1/How-can-I-learn-to-program-in-Python)

Comment: @AseemBansal I don't think you will find a good place on stackexchange for this type of question. Having a clear focus is a big advantage to keep the place professionnal, and attract skilled people on specific topics. That means (sadly) that some questions cannot be asked.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Add the comment into the answer so that I can accept the answer.